# Is there a reliable way of getting Armour piercing weapons?

Tags: heat-signature

I have a character who I feel is ready to tackle the personal story mission, but whenever I go to complete it, there are armoured units. I have a good arsenal of weapons, but nothing that lets me knock them out or kill them.

Is there a reliable way of getting weapons to deal with them?

I have the usual teleport traps, but nothing else.

Comment: I'm almost sure that is rng. You can check the shops and buy mystery boxes. I once got an armor-piercing shortblade. Other than that just raid random ships until you get a good weapon from there (Commenting instead of answering because this isnt a reliable way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take a good look at your liberation map, and try to liberate areas that unlock good weapons in the shop.

My shop now *always* offers a Armour Piercing Shortblade (the yellow rarity one) for 35 (credits?).

Some of the unlocks from liberations state "Make xxx Permanently available in the shop."  Those are the ones you want to look for to make it easy.

That's the most reliable way I know of.  If you're feeling a bit riskier and want an adventure, you can always go on your own looting adventures without taking a quest.  Usually ships have junk; but every once in awhile they will have a lot of chests.  I got one that had like 3-5 orange (rechargeable) items on it.